# .addEventListener vs .onclick

Tags: javascript

I keep reading that there is no difference between the two but I am writing a quiz app and am seeing some differences

For example:

```
Quiz.prototype.handleGuess = function (id, guess) {
    let button = document.getElementById(id);

    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        quiz.guess(guess);
        console.log(guess);

    }

    if(!quiz.hasEnded){
        quiz.displayNext();
    } else {
        quiz.displayScore();
    };
};
```

When using an event listener, I will log the guess to the console on the first button choice. When I choose an answer for the second question the console will read not only the new selection but also the choice I made from the previous question. This does not happen when using .onclick() and I am not sure why!

Comment: `addEventListener` allows you to bind more than one event handler to the same event, whereas `.onclick` will overwrite any existing one. So your code is doing something wrong.

Comment: That must be it then. When I run multiple events on the button when using .assEventListener it must be keeping all instances of "guess" that are passed through.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the following code:

```js
var el1 = document.getElementById("someEl1"),
  el2 = document.getElementById("someEl2");

function firstHandler() {
  alert("First handler");
}

function secondHandler() {
  alert("Second handler");
}

el1.addEventListener("click", firstHandler);
el1.addEventListener("click", secondHandler);

el2.onclick = firstHandler;
el2.onclick = secondHandler;
```

```html
<div id="someEl1">First Element</div>
<div id="someEl2">Second Element</div>
```

In case 1, clicking on `el1` will alert with both messages.  In case 2, clicking on `el2` will only alert with the second because we overwrote what `onclick` does with the second assignment.

`addEventListener` effectively assigns a callback to some internal array of listener callbacks that will **all** be called whenever the event is triggered.

`onclick` is a single property with a single value.  When you assign to it, the old value is replaced by the new assignment.

---

I would highly suggest that you do not use the `onclick` method.  It makes code harder to maintain.  If you are in a large code base and you set the `onclick` of an element and then later on another coder also sets the `onclick` without knowing that that element already had its `onclick` set, then you will run into a difficult time trying to figure out why your code is broken all of a sudden.  Using the event listener pattern makes for more extensible and decoupled code.

Comment: I was thinking, since both of my selected answer were logged, it must have to do with something about listeners and an array. Thank you for this. So basically only use eventListeners if you want multiple items bound to the event?

Comment: @CollinDeSoto see my extra edit.  Essentially, I would suggest that you **never** use the `onclick` way of doing things.

Comment: I see, well I'll have to figure out why my app logs both my first and second choice when answering a my second question. Because of this, I get a false returned when checking the answer, even when I select the correct answer.

Comment: @CollinDeSoto do you still have the `onclick` defined?  I don't believe the 2 ways of doing things aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: No, if I add the listener I remove the onclick. When I select my answer for my second question I get my first answer and my second answer. Unless there is a way to reset the guess.