# Javascript onclick event listners works only sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

So, I'm trying to add an "edit" button before dynamic "post" is shown in the `<div>`. I want to add event listener to this "edit" button when clicked. However, it works as desired(onclick works and "edit clicked" is printed on console) only when I append this "edit" at certain position in my code(code-2), ie, when there is no change to the innerHTML of parent `<div>` after appending this button, but that's not how the UI is demanded.

When it is not working, CODE-1(this is where I want "edit" in UI)

```
let post_div = document.createElement('div');
let edit = document.createElement('div');
edit.style.color = 'blue';
edit.innerHTML = 'Edit';
post_div.append(edit);
let htmlsegment2 = `
    <div id="post-data">${post.post_data}</div>
    <div style="color: grey;">${post.timestamp}</div>`;
post_div.innerHTML += htmlsegment2;
edit.onclick = function(){
    console.log("edit clicked");
}
post_div.className = 'all-posts';
document.querySelector('#all-posts').append(post_div);
```

When I change the position of appended line, it starts working CODE-2

```
let post_div = document.createElement('div');
let edit = document.createElement('div');
edit.style.color = 'blue';
edit.innerHTML = 'Edit';
let htmlsegment2 = `
      <div id="post-data">${post.post_data}</div>
      <div style="color: grey;">${post.timestamp}</div>`;
post_div.innerHTML += htmlsegment2;
 edit.onclick = function(){
      console.log("edit clicked");
}   
post_div.append(edit);
post_div.className = 'all-posts';
document.querySelector('#all-posts').append(post_div);
```

Answer (score 1):

The key difference is the order of these 2 statements, which is different between the two examples:

1:

```
post_div.append(edit);
```

2:

```
post_div.innerHTML += htmlsegment2;
```

In the first (non-working) snippet, 1) happens first, then 2). The problem here is that 2) completely replaces the `innerHTML` of the `post_div`. It replaces it with a copy of what was there before, with the content of `htmlsegment2` added at the end. It's just a shorthand for:

```
post_div.innerHTML = post_div.innerHTML + htmlsegment2;
```

and hopefully seeing it in that form makes it clearer that the entire `innerHTML` gets thrown away and then replaced. Although the result will still contain the same HTML content, it importantly won't maintain the presence of the DOM element you've called `edit` as a child of `post_div`. This means that when you later set `edit.onclick`, you're setting an attribute of an element that *isn't actually in the DOM* - therefore nothing noticeable actually happens.

In the second snippet, 2) happens first, which means that `edit` is appended to `post_div` and not replaced thereafter - so any manipulations of `edit` do apply to an element in the actual DOM.

Hopefully that makes sense as to what the difference is between the two snippets. I would say as a general point that your code has some issues - assigning strings of HTML directly to the `innerHTML` property isn't very maintainable, and using the `+=` operator with `innerHTML` has some common gotchas, of which your question is an example (and it's also quite inefficient). And it's much better to use the `addEventListener` method than assign to the `onclick` property (although both are much better than inline event listeners in HTML, admittedly).

Comment: thanks for the clarification @RobinZigmond, I understand that there is issue with my code. However, what would you siggest I do to get "edit" before htmlsegment2?
Also, will `addEventListener` and `onclick` wont act the same way? Actually, I'm very new to JavaScript, your help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: See the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661707/addEventListener-vs-onclick) question for why `addEventListener` is better than `onclick`. As for how to do what you want, there are a number of ways - one would be to use the `append` method on `htmlsegment2` instead of `+=` with the `innerHTML` property (it accepts an HTML string as well as an actual DOM element).